# Linked list insert function return question

Tags: python, linked-list, return

```
def insert(self, root, item):
    # Given the root/head of a Linked List, append the item to the end of the Linked List
    # Function should return the root/head of the Linked List
    if root is None:
        return Node(item)
    else:
        current = root
        while current.next is not None:
            current = current.next
        current.next = Node(item)
        return root
```

I am having hard time understanding the return statement of the function.

In the code, I haven't updated the root but when I return root, insert function works just fine. In my opinion it should not, since it is not updated and same as the beginning. Could you help me understand this please? I am really wondering what is happening there.

Comment: " In my opinion it should not, since it is not updated and same as the beginning. " So what? comments say that the function should return the head. this is what it is documented to do presumably, although, it doesn't have to. why shouldn't it return the head?

Comment: The caller expects the function to return the list, because when the head is initially `None` it has to return the new Node.

Comment: Presumably the return value could indicate a problem with the creation of a new list (in case `None` is passed as root). Check the definition of `Node` to know what happens if it fails.

Comment: @jcoppens why do you presume that there is a problem? The OP states that his code works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Joooeey, There could be problems if the memory runs out, or if the instanciation of a new `Node()` isn't possible for another reason. These can be problems which are not immediately detectable.

Comment: @jcoppens the OP could also go bankrupt. However, as it stands, the only problem the OP seems to have is that he doesn't understand why his code works.

Comment: The definition looks a bit odd; if you have a class representing a linked list, you shouldn't need to pass a reference to the head of that list as an argument. It's the one piece of data that should already be stored in `self` as an attribute.

Comment: If the only thing this function does is return a reference to a new node when the list is ostensibly empty, then it hasn't actually inserted anything in the list yet; that seems to have been delegated to whoever *calls* `insert`. Maybe this is just a helper function used by the class, but it's still looks suspiciously incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is, find out before reading on.

You do modify the linked list throughout your `else` block:

1. `current = root` gives the object known as `root` the other name `current`.
2. With a linked-list of length 3, the while-block is equivalent to: `current = current.next.next.next` which is exactly the same object as `root.next.next.next`
3. `current.next = Node(item)` is therefore the same as `root.next.next.next = Node(item)`
4. Then you `return root`. And the linked list that starts with `root` does indeed have four elements now with the new `Node(item)` at the end.

---

If the `Node` class is sensibly implemented, and the original linked list has at least two items, the `root` object will indeed not change in the process. But the linked list changes.

That the other elements of the linked list are not part of `root` is not obvious for those not familiar with Python. However, the object bound to `root.next` is not part of the `root` object's value. The `root` object only stores `id(root.next)` which acts as the link.

Comment: On this: current = root
I presumed that I created a new object that is entirely distinct from root. 

If the root will not change, then how does the linked list change, I am confused.

Comment: To understand how name binding works in Python, check out this link: https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/

Comment: Regardless of programming language, in a properly implemented linked list, the `root` node changes if and only if its contents change or a second node is added or replaced. Everything else is the job of the remaining nodes.

Comment: The root changes when the second node is added but not after that. I've edited my answer to include a precise explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The function you have presented does not intend to assign anything to `root`: that would be useless, since it is a local name, and the caller has no access to it.

Instead, this function provides the *new* value of the root as *return* value. It is the responsibility of the caller to assign this value back to *their* root name.

But, this function seems to be an **instance method** as it takes `self` as argument. And that makes it bad practice: this function doesn't use `self`, and so it *shouldn't* be an instance method.

There are at least two ways to change this function to something acceptable:

### 1. Stand-alone function

It could be turned into a stand alone function -- without `self` -- (or a static/class method) and be used like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next=None

def insert(root, item):  # No self parameter
    if root is None:
        return Node(item)
    else:
        current = root
        while current.next is not None:
            current = current.next
        current.next = Node(item)
        return root

# Helper function to traverse a linked list
def values(root):
    while root:
        yield root.value
        root = root.next


head = None
# Note how the caller takes the return value to be the new value of `head`
head = insert(head, 1)
head = insert(head, 2)
head = insert(head, 3)
print(*values(head))  # 1 2 3
```

### 2. Method of a Linked List class

The function could be a proper *instance method*, but then it wouldn't have a `root` parameter, nor would it return the root. In that case, the `root` would be an attribute of the instance, and the `insert` method would update it when needed:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next=None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        
    def insert(self, item):  # No root parameter, no return 
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(item)
        else:
            current = self.root
            while current.next is not None:
                current = current.next
            current.next = Node(item)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.root
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next
    

lst = LinkedList()
lst.insert(1)
lst.insert(2)
lst.insert(3)
print(*lst)  # 1 2 3
```

But the code you presented is a bad mix of the two.